# how to find percent between two timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp, progress-bar

Hello people :)
How can i get the percent between to unix timestamps (I need to use it to my progress bar)

If i have for example 1303248948 and 1303252200. How can i the found out what the percent is out of 100% percent.

So my progress bar constantly can change the width when the first timestamp comes closer to the second timestamp.

So it will be: width="1%" and width="2%" and so on, until it reach 100% in width.

Hope someone can help me! ;-)

Comment: What's start point of your progress bar? Zero? Edit: if 1303252200 stands for 100% ,what value stands for 0%?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, you need 3 time stamps:

starting stamp, current stamp (progress), finish stamp

I'm assuming the current stamp is the current `time()`. In which case;

```
$begin= strtotime('-2 weeks');
$now = time();
$end = strtotime('+2 weeks');

$percent = ($now-$begin) / ($end-$begin) * 100;
```

Note: In the above example, `$percent` should be 50%.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that was what i needed! :)

Comment: Welcome! don't forget to mark as answer if it helped you enough.

Comment: Just a note: the strtotime() in your $end has an extra "t" (I can't edit since it's less than 6 chars).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty simple range mapping problem. Given the value *t* in the range [a, b] you need to map it to an equivalent value in the range [c, d].

First you'll want to map *t* into the range [0, 1]

*x* = (*t* - a) / (b - a)

Second you'll want to map that value *x* to the range [c, d]

*t'* = x * (d - c) + c

This is actually a pretty handy general equation that I use frequently for all kinds of problems and remembering how to construct it is really handy.

Comment: Christian gave me a very good and usefull answer 5 minutes ago, but thanks for your time, Kevin! :-)

Comment: Explaining further: `x = (t - a) / (b - a)` => `position = (now - begin) / (end - begin)` and `t' = x * (d - c) + c` => `percent = position * (100 - 0) + 0`