# HTML/CSS progress bar controlled by Joomla Session Variable ( expiration date)

Tags: php, session, variables, joomla, progress

I am trying to use the progress bar to display how long a user has left in a subscription. I've looked around quite a bit but cannot find a way to use a date to control the css %

http://jsfiddle.net/vjNpj/1298/

I am displaying users account expiration with this code

```
<?php
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('exp_date');?>
```

and it displays MM/DD/YYYY

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the percent between the two dates.
This post should help.

[how to find percent between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723017/how-to-find-percent-between-two-timestamps)

```
$begin= strtotime('-2 weeks');
$now = time();
$end = strtottime('+2 weeks');

$percent = ($now-$begin) / ($end-$begin) * 100;
```